# Rails routing for has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm working on a rails 4 API for a sports team where I have players and teams and I'm struggling a little with rails routing and a `has_many` relationship. My relationship between players and teams looks like:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Searchable
  validates :title, presence: true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Searchable
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end
```

I'd like to be able to add an existing player to a team, but I'm unsure of how to change my `routes.rb` file. Currently, it looks like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json },
            constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/'  do
    scope module: :v1 do
      resources :users, :only               => [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]
      resources :teams, :only               => [:show, :create, :update, :destroy, :index]
      resources :players, :only             => [:show, :create, :update, :destroy, :index]
      resources :sessions, :only            => [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end
end
```

which allows for CRUD operations on players and teams models. I was thinking that for adding a player to an existing team, my route would need to look like:

```
/teams/:team_id/add_player/
```

but I'm unsure of how to declare that route in `routes.rb`. So, a couple of questions:

1. Does that route make sense to people from a REST-ful perspective? If so, how would I declare this route in `routes.rb`
2. Should it be a PATCH or a POST method for adding a player to a team?

Thanks for any help offered,

Sean

Comment: Love how you've formatted your routes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare this route like this:

```
resources :teams, only: [:show, :create, :update, :destroy, :index] do
  put 'add_player', on: :member
end
```

It will map the route to the `add_player` action in your `TeamsController`.

From the REST-ful perspective i would suggest you to make this in the `players#update` action though, since you are basically changing the player record.

Comment: Thanks for that Yury. I took a crack at it with https://github.com/rgbycch/rgbycch-rest/commit/c0bfa497e04b4e1fc0fde1ffe89ed15382301c06, but my unit test fails with a `stack level too deep` error. 
  1) Api::V1::TeamsController PUT/PATCH #update User is logged in adding a player to a team 
     Failure/Error: put :add_player, { user_id: @user.id, id: @team.id, player_id: @player.id }
     SystemStackError:
       stack level too deep
     # /Users/sean.oshea/.rvm/gems

Comment: You have the error because of the serialization in both `team`and `player`. There is an open issue for this: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/211

Comment: Thanks Yury. That works nicely for me after addressing my serializers. Hopefully, they'll get that fixed in the next release of rails.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use a [nested resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :teams, only: [....] do
   resources :players, path: "", path_names: {new: "add_player", create: "add_player", destroy: "remove_player" }, only: [:create, :destroy] #-> /v1/teams/:team_id/add_player
end
```

This will route to your `players_controller`, passing the `:team_id` param:

```
#app/controllers/players_controller.rb
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @players = Player.all
   end

   def create
      if params[:team_id]
        @team = Team.find params[:team_id]
        @player = Player.find params[:id]
        @team.players << player
      else
        # normal "create" action
      end
   end

   def destroy
      if params[:team_id]
          @team = Team.find params[:id]
          @player = Player.find params[:id]
          @team.players.delete player
      end
   end
end
```

You'd be able to couple this with the following view:

```
#app/views/players/new.html.erb
<%= form_tag team_players_path do %> #-> method should be "post"
   <%= collection_select :player, :id, @players, :id, :name %>
   <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

--

**Trivia:**

With HABTM, you get the [`<<`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) & `collection.delete` methods -- both allowing you to add and remove objects from a collection super simply.

-

> Does that route make sense to people from a REST-ful perspective? If so, how would I declare this route in `routes.rb`

Yep.

> Should it be a PATCH or a POST method for adding a player to a team?

In line with the resourceful routing structure, I'd say you could get away with a `POST` request to the `create` action, but it could be done a number of ways!

---

## Update

Do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :teams, only: [....] do
   match "players/:id", to: "players", via: [:put, :delete]
end
```

This will create the following routes:

```
#put      url.com/teams/:team_id/players/:id
#destroy  url.com/teams/:team_id/players/:id
```

This will allow you to use a `players` method in your `teams` controller:

```
#app/controllers/teams_controller.rb
class TeamsController < ApplicationController
   def players
      @team = Team.find params[:team_id]
      @player = Player.find params[:id]
      if request.put?
         @team.players << player
      elsif request.delete?
         @team.players.destroy player
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Rich. I think it feels like an update rather than a create or a destroy. I took a pop at it with https://github.com/rgbycch/rgbycch-rest/commit/c0bfa497e04b4e1fc0fde1ffe89ed15382301c06. Is there a way to make it work using your method using updates instead of creates and destroys?

Comment: I needed to specify the controller as well as the action as I was getting the error `Missing :action key on routes definition`. So I ended up with `match "players/:id", to: "teams#players", via: [:put, :delete] `