# Nested URLs, controllers and views in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, nested, controllers

What I am trying to do is to nest my pages in Rails for example:

```
www.mysite.com/fifa17/ps4
```

This way, once I am on the *show.html.erb*, I can use use the route to sell my product for specifically that game on that console platform..

At the moment, I have a `Console` model with `has_many :games` and a `Game` model with `has_many :consoles`, but I can't get the routing and views to work. Do I have just one controller or two?

I have both the `Games` and `Consoles` seeded under *ActiveRecords* by `name`.
I seem to be able to call one of the actions (i.e. `Console.name`) but cannot call both the console name and Game name.

Comment: Start with changing the associations. Seems like it is a case of *HMT* or *HABTM*

Comment: Update the question with `Game` and `Console` models.

Comment: Your models should be using `has_and_belongs_to_many`. (Or `has_many through: your_join_table`).

Comment: use has many through, do not use has and belongs to many.

Answer (score 1):

A great place to read on this would be in Ruby on Rails [Associations Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and [Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

What you want to do, is to update your `Console` and `Game` associations, to use `has_and_belongs_to_many`. You can read more on that [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)

And double check your routing, check this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364584/rails-routing-for-has-and-belongs-to-many-relationship) for a similar case.