# Correct Routing for :has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes, associations

Ok so.. I have a site with several dropdown menus in my navbar. It goes a little like this:

Gran Turismo (First title drops down to: )

- PS4
- PS3 etc.

Forza (Second title drops down to: )

- PS4
- PS3 etc..

> My goal is when I click on one of the drop downs it will display a Show page using the routes:

```
www.mysite.com/forza/ps4
```

Everyone tells me that I should use a `has_many :through` to a third model which I have called Platform.

My models are therefore this:

```html
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :platforms
  has_many :consoles, through: :platforms
end

class Console < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :platforms
  has_many :games, through: :platforms
end

class Platform < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :console
end
```

And my routes are this:

```
  resources :platforms, only: [:show] do
    resources :games do
      resources :consoles
    end
  end
```

Ideally, on the final show.html.erb which im guessing would be the platforms show, I would like to display the product I am selling specifically for the game Forza on the platform PS4 which I chose my selecting the dropdown menu of my choosing..

However my routes are coming up like this instead:

```
/platforms/:platform_id/games/:game_id/consoles/:id(.:format)
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? And if there's a much easier way around this?

Many thanks!

**Update:**

"Platform" could be slightly confusing. Perhaps "MarketPlace" would be better suited. Although reading it through now, maybe I shouldn't have a third model and just end it at Console.

I just want the final show page to be slightly different if a different Game is selected.

Comment: And what do you expect your drop down menu to be

Comment: It looks to me like all you *really* need is a route like: `/platforms/:id`; but instead you'd like to "alias" this route as `/:game_name/:console_name`. This is [possible](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments), but can be difficult to get right. What if you used a route that's easier to match against - e.g. `/platform?game_name=<...>&console_name=<...>`? This is still against rails conventions, but would be easier to build.

Comment: PS4 is a console and Forza is a Game. What will be a name for platform?

Comment: @Pavan I can see the purpose of the model, but the naming is confusing. Perhaps something like `GameRelease` is better? The `name` could be `"Forza for PS4"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested URLs, controllers and views in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906304/nested-urls-controllers-and-views-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: @TomLord Lord, Yes I see what you mean! I definitely don't want to make it too complicated.. All im trying to get is a final show page that brings in the selection that one makes on the site (ie. game and console)

Comment: @TomLord I was referring to OP. I'm confused between console and platform :)

Comment: What is the difference of each game between consoles? Do you have different records in your db for each game and console? For example, `Forza` is unique in `Game` model or you have multiple `Forza` (i.e. one for each `Console`) records?

Comment: Sorry @Pavan, yes "Platform" is confusing haha As one said, it could be GameRelease or MarketPlace for selling items directly for the Game on that Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve the exact route you want (e.g. `www.mysite.com/forza/ps4`) using a custom route, like this:

```
get "/:game/:console", to: "games#show"
```

In `GamesController` you could retrieve both parameters and search for the `Game` you want to display, something like this:

```
def show
  @console = Console.find_by(name: params[:console])
  @game    = Game.find_by(name: params[:game])
  # ...
end
```

Keep in mind that this will work consistently only if all of the following conditions are met:

- `Game` model contains **unique** names (or whatever column you chose to use as *slug*).
- You have no other routes with the same pattern (e.g. */:other/:route*).
- `Game` names are **different** from any model name (unless that model has custom routes to handle the conflict, or not routes at all).
- The route is defined **at the end** of your routes so it won't interfere with other routes.

Comment: Also note: As I eluded to in the comments above, this routing approach is "error prone" because, if you're not careful, you could get conflicts. There's a good reason why rails provides RESTful routes, like `/platorms/:id`, instead of this... For example, what happens if you have two "platforms"/"game releases" for the same game name and console -- e.g. a "limited edition" release? This route will conflict.

Comment: @TomLord You are right, this approach must be used carefully. Regarding the possible conflict with _two "platforms"/"game releases"_, it shouldn't be an issue since this answer considers only `Game` and `Console` models (because of OP's last edit). So, as long as `Game` and `Console` have unique names, this should work.

Comment: Yes, agreed... But (1) *is* the game name unique? (The original post never clarified this.) And (2) are there any *other* non-RESTful routes like this, that could cause conflicts? (The original post never showed the full `routes.rb`.) You could even get a route conflict if there is a game called `foo` and a model called `Foo`!

Comment: @TomLord Haven't thought about the edge case where a model could be named as a game, that would be a problem (about _1_ and _2_ i _assumed_ unique names and no other routes like this). Thanks for your comments, i'll add some notes to clarify when this could work.

Comment: Thanks guys! This is exactly what I need, as there will be only a few "games" and they will all be different in name (No special editions either!) :) I do have one final question, in the games controller under Show, the :name shows me an error "undefined method 'name' ", but if I put id: and change the url it works fine.. Could this be a problem with using uppercase in my ActiveRecords and so in the url when I call in lowercase it would not work? Or is it something different? Sorry for bothering you guys!

Comment: @Alec If the db column is written with uppercase (i.e. `NAME`) you will need to use `Game.find_by(NAME: params[:game]` instead. The url (route) doesn't matter as `:game` and `:console` are only the names of the parameters, you can use any name tou want. If it is up to you, i will recommend naming all columns with *snake_case*.

Comment: @Gerry Thanks, yes all columns are in lowercase which is why Im a little confused.. Im sure ill figure out the problem though.